# Wpf ComboboxEdit from binding global list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, devexpress

```
  <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate>
         <dxe:ComboBoxEdit 
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
           ItemsSource="{Binding HizmetSaglayiciList}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Hiz_Sag_Id, Mode=TwoWay}"
           ValueMember="Hiz_Sag_Id"
           IsTextEditable="False"
           AllowNullInput="False" 
           AutoComplete="False"                               
           ImmediatePopup="False" 
           EditMode="InplaceActive"/>
       </ControlTemplate>
 </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
```

I have global list called `HizmetSaglayiciList`, but 
The combobox does not open when I press the edit button.

I am writing missing any place.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those cases in which the DataContext is not accessible as certain elements (in this case dxg:GridColumn) are not part of visual or logical tree. A solution may be using a Freezable class. Check this [Link](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Answer (score 0):

DataContext for the `ComboBoxEdit` is not the same as for the `GridControl`, that's why ItemSource binding fails. Assuming your `GridControl` has a name (let's say it's `x:Name="gridTest"`), you can simply do the following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.HizmetSaglayiciList, ElementName=gridTest}"
```

Actually, you can bind `ItemSource` to any named element's `DataContext`.